# How to move log files automatically at midnight?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I m working on a project in which m using logback.xml for logging configuration and logs are rotating and rolling fine.But i want to move log files into other folder at midnight using configuration setting in logback.xml. Please help me!

However I have done it using scheduler.

Comment: If you're using [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/), why did you tag [Log4j](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/)?

Comment: Write your own `Appender`

Comment: Please post the content of **logback.xml** also.